# What do the Shorinji Kempo Organisations do?

Tags: philosophy

I'm approaching my 1st Kyu grading for Shorinji Kempo.  But I'm having trouble with one of the essay topics.

I know next to nothing about Shorinji Kempo Organizations within Japan yet I'm supposed to write a page long essay on them.  The only source book I can find is the Tokuhon.  The standard textbook for WSKO kenshi.

The organizations are as follows (straight from the Tokuhon)

1. World Shorinji Kempo Organisation (this is the bit I belong to so
   I know about this)
2. Foundation Shorinji Kempo Federation (like WSKO but japan only I think)
3. Kongo Zen Sohonzan Shorinji (this is the religious organisation with the buzen monks)
4. Zenrin Gakuen (a 'school' apparently possibly even something akin to a university, but I have no idea for what age group or what it teaches other than shorinji kempo)
5. Shorinji Kempo Unity (this is the part that seems largely interested in intellectual property.  I know they brought and lost a law suit against the (defect) BSKF in the UK over IP.)

For example if I want to gain a Hokei (Philosophy) rank.  Which organisation would this be?

Comment: Try asking here  http://www.e-budo.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?24-Shorinji-Kempo   It doesn't seem very active though maybe someone will respond if they see a post. Good luck.  They didn't have essays when I got my 1st kyu in 1983.